# The different Egos in Husserl's Cartesian Meditations

Tags: phenomenology, husserl

So I thought I had understood the different 'Egos', mainly the distinction between the psychological and transcendental Ego, in the text. But throughout meditation 2 it becomes a bit confusing to me, so I figured I would ask for some guidance. Husserl uses the concepts of: transcendental Ego, Personal Ego, Concrete Ego, identical Ego, Psychological Ego and the Pure Ego, which of these expressions can be used synonymously and what are the most important differences, especially between the transcendental and concrete ego?

Comment: Husserl's transcendental ego, pure ego (purest form of representation of transcendental ego) and identical ego could be said to be synonymous in some sense and force which is the the foundation of all phenomenological inquiry and is not itself an object of experience but the source from which all experiences emerge. The same goes for his personal ego, concrete ego and psychological ego which presumably can be empirically tested or falsified such as psychology and cognitive sciences, they all refer to the individual subject within the world of lived experience...